# Use a closure for the PDO FETCH instructions

Tags: php, pdo, closures

It occurs to me that I want to give my PDO result the instructions on how to instantiate itself into an object when it gets iterated later on, but I do not want to perform the logic until that time.

I've been looking for the existence of this PDO functionality but I cannot find it. What I want to do is essentially this:

```
public function getUsers()
{
    $sql = 'select first_name, last_name, phone, address from users';

    return $this->pdo->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC, function($row) {
        $user = new User();
        $user->setName($row['first_name'] . ' ' .$row['last_name'])
             ->setPhoneNumber($row['phone'])
             ->setMailingAddress($row['address']);
        return $user;
    });
}
```

Is there a good way of accomplishing this with PHP and specifically PDO? Looping through the iterator is not an acceptable answer. I only want to iterate on this recordset once during execution.

Comment: Do you want the `User` objects to be instantiated lazily, or the entire query to be executed lazily?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a Generator for this via `yield`. Only when the internal pointer is on certain iteration, the concrete object will be yielded.

```
class User {
    public $picture;

    public function __construct($pic) {
        $this->picture = $pic;
    }
}

function getUsers() {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=users', 'root', '');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM votesusers";
    $res = $pdo->query($query);
    while ($row = $res->fetch()) {
        yield new User($row['picture_id']);
    }
}

foreach (getUsers() as $user) {
    var_Dump($user);
}
```

Output:

```
object(User)[5]
  public 'picture' => string '2' (length=1)

object(User)[6]
  public 'picture' => string '9' (length=1)

object(User)[5]
  public 'picture' => string '6' (length=1)

object(User)[6]
  public 'picture' => string '1' (length=1)
```

Comment: Note: requires PHP 5.5 which [is still not widely adopted](http://w3techs.com/technologies/history_details/pl-php/5/q).

Comment: Thanks @Royal Bg this is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a custom lazy-loading collection that implements the [`Iterator`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php) interface. Here's an example:

```
class LazyCollection implements Iterator
{
    private $stmt;
    private $callback;

    public function __construct(PDOStatement $stmt, Closure $callback)
    {
        $this->stmt = $stmt;
        $this->callback = $callback;
    }

    public function current()
    {
        $callback = $this->callback; // required because PHP is silly
        return $callback($this->stmt->fetch());
    }

    /* rest of interface implementation */
}
```

And you would use it like this:

```
$stmt = $this->pdo->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)
$result = new LazyCollection($stmt, function($row) {
    return new User($row['name'], $row['phone'], $row['address']);
});

foreach($result as $user)
{
    // $user is an instance of User
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably something like this:

```
$result = $this->pdo->query($sql, PDO::FETCH_CLASS, 'User');
return $result->fetch();
```

Comment: This would work if my objects didn't require explicit mapping. What I'm looking for is a way to add more specific instructions. The example doesn't really give that impression but it's more about mapping database columns to classes that don't have a clean property to column mapping.